# Request Headers not available in WCF Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have an aspx web page which adds a custom header to the outgoing request to my web service:

```
    using (MyWebServiceClient wsClient = new MyWebsiteWebServiceClient())
    {
        using (new OperationContextScope(wsClient.InnerChannel))
        {
            // Add a HTTP Header to an outgoing request
            HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            requestMessage.Headers["Authorization"] = Token;
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;

            Session["success"] = wsClient.MyMethod();
        }
    }
```

As far as I can tell, the header gets added to the outgoing request OK.

My code in the called webservice:

```
public bool MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        IncomingWebRequestContext request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
        WebHeaderCollection headers = request.Headers;

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Doesn't have the supplied header in the `headers` obtained.

I got the code snippets used by searching here and elsewhere.
What am I doing wrong, please?

Thanks

Comment: are you able to access that application through a browser? If so, I recommend looking in chrome to see if you can see the response header. See how to do that here: https://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/

Comment: It's a Request Header I'm working with, not a Response Header...